# Has or Have with name?

Tags: american-english

Which is correct?

1) Has their board voted yet?
2) Have their board voted yet?

Or does it depend whether we are using American English (Has their board . . .) or British English (Have their board . . .)?

Thanks.

Comment: -- Wrong forum --

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular) Related: [*Over half our board and staff **are/is** people of color*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203064/)

Comment: Yes, it is partly a BrE vs. AmE thing, though some on either side of the pond might deny it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be either. If the writer intends to consider the board members individually, *have* is correct. If instead the writer considers the board members one unified group, *has* is correct.

Comment: So I guess since in the context of voting, the board will be voting individually, "have" is the better choice. You agree? Thanks.